# CSS Classes on Single Element

Tags: css

Hello I'm having some issues with CSS on my blog. My Wordpress theme has a post styles section in the CSS file which have a class "Entry" in which "a" attribute is defined for the links inside the article area.
I generated a button from css generator and inserted the button in an article that is pointing to some other website using href. My CSS file has something like this,

```
.Entry a{color:black;text-decoration:underline};

.button {background:black;color:white And some other Styling};
```

I used this code to display the button.

```
<a href="some link" class="button">Go to this link</a>
```

Without the use of class="button", the link follow the Entry a property. But when I use class with it, it display the button with the mixture of Entry a and class button styles. I don't want the button to use Entry a properties. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could rewrite the first rule using the [CSS3 `:not` pseudo-class selector](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3anot) as

```
.Entry a:not(.button) {color:black;text-decoration:underline}
```

This will do what you need, but it's not supported by IE versions earlier than 9.

A true cross-browser solution is more involved: you would need to "undo" the attributes that `.Entry a` applies in your `.button` rule. For example:

```
.Entry a {color:black;text-decoration:underline}

.button {color:white;text-decoration:none;background:black}
```

**Update: I forgot something quite important.**

If you do go the "undo" route you will need to make sure that the "undoing" selector has [specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) at least equal to that of the first selector. I recommend reading the linked page (it's not long) to get to grips with the concept; in this specific case to achieve this you have to write `a.button` instead of simply `.button`.

Comment: I've liked that, didn't know about this selector, I guess it's CSS3?

Comment: @Nuxy: Yes, CSS3. Added a link to the W3C wiki.

Comment: Although your `:not()` approach sounds reasonable at this stage, sooner or later you'll need to define new styles which get overridden by `.Entry a`. Eventually, you'll end up in a maintenance nightmare with ridiculously long `:not()` clauses. The *real* problem is the specificity of the selectors, and that's what you need to target in order to solve it.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens: I see your point, but IMHO it is entirely possible that there will be no such problem in the future since we 're talking about a non-professional making a few tweaks to a WP theme. If CSS3 support is not a problem I consider `:not` a very good practical solution here.

Answer (score 2):

For avoid `.Entry a` CSS styles to be applied at when you use the selector `.button` you should overwritte with the selector `.button` all the properties defined in `.Entry a`

For example:

```
.Entry a{color:black;text-decoration:underline};

.button {color:white;text-decoration:none;background:black;color:white And some other Styling};
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `.Entry a` has a higher specificity than `.button`. The result is that your element receives its actual `background` property from `.button` but its `color` and `text-decoration` properties come from `.Entry a`.

There are a few ways to "fix" this:

- **Increase the specificity of the `.button` selector.**
  For example, if you only use `.button` on `a` tags, you could change the selector to `a.button`. This new selector would have the same specificity as `.Entry a` (one tag value and one class value), so the "winner" is decided by the source order. If `a.button` comes after `.Entry a` in the CSS file, `a.button` takes the upperhand.
- **Decrease the specificity of the `.Entry a` selector.**
  Do you really need to target only `a` tags inside `.Entry` elements? Can you get away with simply making it a base style for all `a` tags? If you can, you can simply change `.Entry a` to `a`. This new selector has only one tag value, which is less specific than the one class value in `.button`.
- **Define extra selectors on `.button`.**
  For example, you could use `.button, a.button` so that the second selector takes over where the first selector fails. Be warned that this could get very messy when you encounter this same problem with other tags such as `input` or `button` tags.
- **<strike>Use `!important`.</strike>**
  Never do this, as you'll get yourself in trouble if you ever try to make a `.big-button` class which needs to override some `.button` styles.

If you want to learn more about specificity, here's a [good article](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) about what it is and how it's calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Well in CSS3 you could do this:

`.Entry a:not(.button)`

That will restrict your `.Entry a` rule from affecting any elements with `.button`.

If CSS3 is not an option (i.e. you need to support IE <= 8) you'll need to overwrite whichever inadvertent styles are being inherited. So for example if your button is ending up with an unwanted border from `.Entry a`, overwrite this in your `.button` rule, e.g.

```
.button { border: none; /* more button styles */ }
```

Comment: This won't actually work, as `.Entry a` is still more specific than `.button`. I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/E3ERE/), see for yourself.

Comment: Well done on the Fiddle. The specificity would need changing, agreed. The first option is the best one - I was merely mentioning the need to overwrite styles if CSS3 is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

You could overwrite any styles in `.button` class that are defined in `.Entry a`

E.g. if you dont want your text to be underlined you could use `text-decoration: none`

```
.Entry a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a.button {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*And some other Styling*/
}
```

Also don't use semicolons after braces `};` in your css. simply use a brace to close `}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Yeah I used semicolon after braces by mistake.

Comment: This won't actually work, as `.Entry a` is still more specific than `.button`. I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/E3ERE/), see for yourself.

Comment: Edited: Right, you will have to use `a.button`. Sorry for that, i missed to add the a :). http://jsfiddle.net/dYVva/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing would be to "undo" the specific styles that your element inherits from the styles for `.Entry a`. For example, to undo the text-decoration style, you could use `text-decoration:none`.

If you only need it to work for newer browsers, then you could use the not() selector @Jon has mentioned.